# How to call dispose when using BLoC pattern and StatelessWidget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to understand BLoC pattern but I cannot figure out where or when to call dispose() in my example.

I am trying to understand various state management techniques in Flutter.

I came up with an example I managed to build with the use of StatefulWidget, scoped_model and streams.

I believe I finally figured out how to make my example work with the use of "BloC" pattern but I have a problem with calling the dispose() method as I use the StatelessWidgets only.

I tried converting PageOne and PageTwo to StatefulWidget and calling dispose() but ended up with closing the streams prematurely when moving between pages.

Is it possible I should not worry at all about closing the streams manually in my example?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<ThemeData>(
      initialData: bloc.themeProvider.getThemeData,
      stream: bloc.streamThemeDataValue,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ThemeData> snapshot) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'bloc pattern example',
          theme: snapshot.data,
          home: BlocPatternPageOne(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

// -- page_one.dart

class BlocPatternPageOne extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('(block pattern) page one'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            buildRaisedButton(context),
            buildSwitchStreamBuilder(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  StreamBuilder<bool> buildSwitchStreamBuilder() {
    return StreamBuilder<bool>(
            initialData: bloc.switchProvider.getSwitchValue,
            stream: bloc.streamSwitchValue,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
              return Switch(
                value: snapshot.data,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  bloc.sinkSwitchValue(value);
                },
              );
            },
          );
  }

  Widget buildRaisedButton(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
            child: Text('go to page two'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return BlocPatternPageTwo();
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          );
  }
}

// -- page_two.dart

class BlocPatternPageTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('(bloc pattern) page two'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            buildRaisedButton(context),
            buildSwitchStreamBuilder(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  StreamBuilder<bool> buildSwitchStreamBuilder() {
    return StreamBuilder<bool>(
            initialData: bloc.switchProvider.getSwitchValue,
            stream: bloc.streamSwitchValue,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
              return Switch(
                value: snapshot.data,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  bloc.sinkSwitchValue(value);
                },
              );
            },
          );
  }

  Widget buildRaisedButton(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
            child: Text('go back to page one'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          );
  }
}

// -- bloc.dart

class SwitchProvider {
  bool _switchValue = false;

  bool get getSwitchValue => _switchValue;

  void updateSwitchValue(bool value) {
    _switchValue = value;
  }
}

class ThemeProvider {
  ThemeData _themeData = ThemeData.light();

  ThemeData get getThemeData => _themeData;

  void updateThemeData(bool value) {
    if (value) {
      _themeData = ThemeData.dark();
    } else {
      _themeData = ThemeData.light();
    }
  }
}

class Bloc {
  final StreamController<bool> switchStreamController =
      StreamController.broadcast();
  final SwitchProvider switchProvider = SwitchProvider();

  final StreamController<ThemeData> themeDataStreamController =
      StreamController();
  final ThemeProvider themeProvider = ThemeProvider();

  Stream get streamSwitchValue => switchStreamController.stream;
  Stream get streamThemeDataValue => themeDataStreamController.stream;

  void sinkSwitchValue(bool value) {
    switchProvider.updateSwitchValue(value);
    themeProvider.updateThemeData(value);
    switchStreamController.sink.add(switchProvider.getSwitchValue);
    themeDataStreamController.sink.add(themeProvider.getThemeData);
  }

  void dispose() {
    switchStreamController.close();
    themeDataStreamController.close();
  }
}

final bloc = Bloc();
```

At the moment everything works, however, I wonder if I should worry about closing the streams manually or let Flutter handle it automatically.

If I should close them manually, when would you call dispose() in my example?

Comment: Use StatefulWidget and read this: https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-persistent-tab-bars-a26220d322bc

Comment: You say that you're trying learn state management techniques that is ok! But   are you trying make a state management into a stateLESS widget?  Think about it!!

Comment: thank you @diegoveloper, your advice is true if I go back to StatefulWidget, however, in the meantime, I learned that there is a way of staying with StatelessWidget but using InheritedWidget to benefit from the dispose() method. I have some more studying to do on the topic.

Comment: @MarcosBoaventura I am trying to understand how correctly separate UI from business logic and drop setState and stateful widgets for BLoC and stream builders, and I want to believe I achieved that to some degree in my example with one question, how to go about disposing streams in a StatelessWidget environment.

Comment: @MarcosBoaventura When using BLOC you don't ncessarily have to use statefulwidget or stateless widget, it really depends on the feature or functionality you need. I was in a similar misconception that we must use "stateless widget" with BLOC as the state is going to be updated anyways from the BLOC events. But it is not true, You may use any of them depending on your requirement for that screen/widget, hope this would help others coming across

Answer (score 1):

You can use provider package for flutter. It has callback for dispose where you can dispose of your blocs. Providers are inherited widgets and provides a clean way to manage the blocs. BTW I use stateless widgets only with provider and streams.

Answer (score 1):

In stateless widget, there is not dispose method so you need not to worry about where to call it.
It's as simple as that

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by disposing the bloc in dispose method. The code implements the bloc pattern.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    @RoutePage()
    class CartView extends StatefulWidget {
      const CartView({super.key});
    
      @override
      State<CartView> createState() => _CartViewState();
    }
    
    class _CartViewState extends State<CartView> {
      final cartBloc = CartBloc();
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        cartBloc.add(CartInitialEvent());
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
        cartBloc.close();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return BlocConsumer<CartBloc, CartState>(
          bloc: cartBloc,
          listenWhen: (previous, current) => current is CartActionState,
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state is CartErrorState) {
              context.router.pop();
              Utilities.flushBarErrorMessage("Couldn't delete from cart", context);
            }
          },
          buildWhen: (previous, current) => current is! CartActionState,
          builder: (context, state) {
            switch (state.runtimeType) {
              case CartLoadingState:
                return const LoadingWidget();
              case CartSuccessLoadedState:
                final cartLoadedState = state as CartSuccessLoadedState;
                final localOrderCartItems =
                    cartLoadedState.localOrderCartModel!.data;
                return BuildLocalShopLoadedView(
                  cartItems: localOrderCartItems![0].cartItems!,
                  cartBloc: cartBloc,
                  cartTotal:
                      cartLoadedState.localOrderCartModel!.data![0].cartTotal,
                  coId: cartLoadedState.localOrderCartModel!.data![0].coId!,
                );
              case CartEmptyLoadedState:
                return Scaffold(
                  // backgroundColor: Colors.g,
                  appBar: const CustomAppBar(
                    appBarTitle: "My Cart",
                  ),
                  body: Padding(
                    padding: AppPadding.kQuatHalfPad,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        LottieBuilder.asset(
                            'assets/lottie/empty-cart-animation.json'),
                        SizedBox(height: 20.h),
                        const AppSmallText(
                          text: 'Your Cart is Empty',
                          fontSize: 23,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10.h),
                        const AppSmallText(
                          text:
                              "Looks like you haven't added anything to your cart yet",
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10.h),
                        PrimaryActionButton(
                          labelText: 'Start shopping',
                          onPressed: () {
                          context.router.popUntilRouteWithName(RoutesName.localShop);
    
                            context.router
                                .popUntilRouteWithName(LocalShopViewRoute.name);
                            
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              default:
                return const SizedBox();
            }
          },
        );
      }
    }
    
    class BuildLocalShopLoadedView extends StatefulWidget {
      final List<CartItem>? cartItems;
      final int? cartTotal;
      final String coId;
      final CartBloc cartBloc;
    
      const BuildLocalShopLoadedView({
        Key? key,
        required this.cartItems,
        required this.cartBloc,
        this.cartTotal = 0,
        required this.coId,
      }) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<BuildLocalShopLoadedView> createState() =>
          _BuildLocalShopLoadedViewState();
    }
    
    class _BuildLocalShopLoadedViewState extends State<BuildLocalShopLoadedView> {
      // final _razorpay = Razorpay();
      String currency = '₹';
    
      // final RazorPayIntegration _integration = RazorPayIntegration();
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        // _integration.intiateRazorPay();
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        // TODO: implement dispose
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: const CustomAppBar(
            appBarTitle: "My Cart",
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
            padding: AppPadding.kSinglePad,
            child: Container(
              height: 90.h,
              padding: AppPadding.kHalfPad,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: AppColors.kBottomSheetLightButtonColor,
                borderRadius: AppBorder.kHalfCurve,
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      const AppSmallText(
                        text: 'Total price',
                        color: AppColors.kDeepAvatarColor,
                      ),
                      AppSmallText(
                        text: '$currency${widget.cartTotal}',
                        color: AppColors.kDeepAvatarColor,
                        fontSize: 30,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10.w,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        //! navigate to checkout view
                        context.navigateTo(const CheckoutViewRoute());
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        elevation: 0.0,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: AppBorder.kHalfCurve,
                        ),
                        backgroundColor: AppColors.kPrimaryButtonColor,
                        minimumSize: const Size(double.maxFinite, double.maxFinite),
                      ),
                      child: const AppSmallText(
                        text: 'CHECKOUT',
                        letterSpacing: 1,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
              padding: AppPadding.kHalfHorizontal,
              child: CartListViewBuilder(
                cartBloc: widget.cartBloc,
                cartItems: widget.cartItems,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```